# Adding a language to the AVM2

Tags: actionscript-3, compiler-construction, language-design, bytecode

I'm interested in making a language to run on the AVM2 and I'm looking for advice on where to start. I do realize that this is by no means a trivial task, but I would like to give it a try and at the very least learn more about implementing a language along the way.

I have messed around with ANTLR and have been reading up on syntax issues for language development. What I'm looking for is advice on a path to take or useful references/books.

For instance I would like to generate (script/manually) some very simple AVM2 bytecode and get that to run on the VM as a start.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not interested in Haxe, you will basically need to write your own compiler that compiles objects down to ABC (Actionscript Byte Code). The [AVM2 Overview](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/avm2overview.pdf) document available from Adobe on ABC and the AVM2 which should help you get started. It's a fairly thorough document but stay alert for a few typo's in the bytecode instructions.

You will also need to wrap the bytecode in a doABC tag as part of a SWF container. You can get more information from the [SWF File Format](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf) documentation.

If you'd like a headstart on writing the data structures (optimised int formats, etc), feel free to checkout the code at asmock, a dynamic mocking project I've been working on. The SWF/ByteCode generation stuff is a bit messy but there are IDataOutput wrappers  ([SWF](https://asmock.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/asmock/trunk/source/ASMock/src/flemit/framework/SWFOutput.as), [ByteCode](https://asmock.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/asmock/trunk/source/ASMock/src/flemit/framework/bytecode/ByteCodeWriter.as)) that might come in handy.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I've just picked those docs up a while back, now to sit down with them. I'll try use the ASMock code to output a simple SWF file that performs some simple arithmetic operations for a start.

Comment: The portion of asmock that generates bytecode (flemit) is not actually documented/supported yet, but if you have any questions feel free to shoot them over.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Haxe](https://haxe.org/): it is an open source language that can target different platforms, including the AVM. You can dig into the SWF compiler source code to get some inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Project Alchemy by Adobe can be a good reference
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/

How did it go?
I'm also interested in doing a Java to AVM2 compiler... 
Do you have any published code?

Comment: I looked into it and found it too much work, although I am still interested in it. Im not interested in translating languages but more making a modified as3.